# Facebook API: All links shared by all friends?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

What is the most practical way to access the links shared by the whole of a users' facebook friends?

I'm looking to scrape all the links to a handful of domains, shared by the friends of the authenticated user.

Is there a way to ask for "All links of domain X", "All links" (and I'll filter for domain X) or do I need to fetch each friend and parse each individual feed? I'm assuming there's a main "Inbound" feed that will be all the links from all the friends. True? Not true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select title, url, owner from link where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() limit 100)
```

will return links shared by friends of the authenticated user. You would then need to filter the urls for the domains you are interested in. Since the URL field in the Link table is not indexed, you cannot perform a WHERE on it in the FQL.

Comment: Adding `ORDER BY created_time DESC` to the outer query made this the ideal answer. Final query:  

`select link_id, title, url, owner, owner_comment, created_time, picture from link where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() LIMIT 100) ORDER BY created_time DESC`

Comment: Great to hear it worked. I've also found that you can add a WHERE clause on the URL field as long you already have a WHERE on one of the indexed fields like owner. So if you are looking for a specific URL, you can do: 

select link_id, title, url, owner, owner_comment, created_time, picture from link where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me() LIMIT 100) and url = 'http:/ /f8.facebook.com/' ORDER BY created_time DESC

Comment: Can this support wildcard searches, like `url LIKE '%youtube.com%'` ?

Comment: @JordanFeldstein No, it does not and it's driving me crazy. You're probably trying to do what I posted here http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8249094/determine-urls-from-my-site-that-where-shared-by-current-user-friends a while ago. No good answers yet.

Answer (score 0):

For domain searching try adding something like WHERE strpos(url,'domain.com') > 0, asside to an indexable column in your where clause.