# Getting all links of any sort shared by a user's facebook friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all links shared by a user's friends I tried all of the queries and requests from the below questions,

[How do I get a friend's links with Facebook's graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226124/how-do-i-get-a-friends-links-with-facebooks-graph-api)

[Finding who shared a link publicly and finding who reshared a given link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565452/finding-who-shared-a-link-publicly-and-finding-who-reshared-a-given-link)

[Facebook API: All links shared by all friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048339/facebook-api-all-links-shared-by-all-friends)

[get shared links on facebook newsfeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179944/get-shared-links-on-facebook-newsfeed)

but unable to figure out what would be the exact FQL or the request URL to get all links shared from my friends from a defined past interval. I am kind of a newbie with the graph API and FQL, so kindly help me in figuring out a way to do this.

I tried a simple query

```
SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, image_urls FROM link WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 100)
```

but I get

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

as the response from the API Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is too long for FQL to construct the answer. If you'll try this:

```
SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, image_urls
       FROM link WHERE owner IN 
       (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 10)
```

(the same query, only limit set to 10 instead of 100) FQL explorer will think ~5-8secs but then give you back the result. Or if you will not receive the result, you have to reduce limit again.

So you have 2 choices:

1. You can lower you limit from 100 to 10 or less and run your query without changes
2. You can run query

   SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()

and then for each received friend ID run another query

```
SELECT link_id, owner, owner_comment, created_time, title, summary, url, image_urls
       FROM link WHERE owner = FRIEND_ID
```

Comment: I guess you are right, I tried limiting the query to 10 also even to 2 but the request fails. I tired the second choice and it seems to work fine but it has the overhead of making so many service calls. Anyways the best possible solution for now is this.